# What is the cause of user;Unknown entry in the RowKey column of Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Recently I noticed a strange entry in the RowKey column under $MetricsHourPrimaryTransactionsTable of Azure Table Storage. The RowKey is `user;Unknown`.

[image]

What is the significance of this entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-metrics-table-schema), we know the RowKey includes user, system, all and api-name types. The user  is specified for all user requests, including anonymous, authenticated, and SAS requests.  For Unknown type, I think it is an api-name.

But in [api-name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages), I didn’t see any logged operations or status messages named ‘Unknown’. So I suppose it belongs to an unknown error. It does not belong to known api-name.